# Set ID attribute on a Snap.svg graphic

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm using **Snap.svg** API and I have three graphics that I need to select in my CSS for styling purposes. Thus, to distinguish between them, I need to give them an ID or class name.

**This is how I create an element:**

```
var draw = Snap(100, 75);
c = draw.polyline(0,0, 50,75, 100,0, 0,0);
c.attr({
    fill: "black"
});
```

**This is the result I get:**

```
<svg height="75" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline points="0,0,50,75,100,0,0,0" style="" fill="#000000"></polyline>
</svg>
```

**This is what I need the result to be:**

```
<svg id="graphic_1" height="75" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline points="0,0,50,75,100,0,0,0" style="" fill="#000000"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update

I raised an issue on GitHub and it looks like this will be [fixed in the next release](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/166). For now, on the development branch, you can use `Element.attr`:

```
var draw = Snap(100, 75);
draw.attr({ id: 'graphic_1' });
```

I'm leaving the original answer below because:

1. at time of writing, this doesn't work in the master (release) version; and
2. the technique described for directly accessing the underlying DOM node might be useful to others in future, or those using an older version of Snap.svg.

---

It's not documented, but internally Snap.svg stores the DOM node in a property called `node`. Thus, you can set the ID of the canvas like so:

```
draw.node.id = 'graphic_1';
```

Alternatively, if you would prefer to avoid undocumented techniques, you could create an element with the ID that you want *first* and use that directly:

```
<svg id="graphic_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="75"></svg>
```

```
var draw = Snap("#graphic_1");
```

Comment: Great! :) Just bear in mind that the `node` property isn't documented—if you go with that approach, be careful if you update to a newer version of Snap.svg at a later date.

Answer (score 5):

With Snap version `0.2.0` the `.attr()` method will work as expected,

```
var draw = Snap(100, 75);
draw.attr({id: "graphic_1"});
```

but with Snap version `0.1.0` I had modify `snap.svg.js` (approx. line 4338) to allow this to work.

```
var availableAttributes = {
    svg: {
        id : "",    
    },
```