# Creating group element with id attribute in snap.svg

Tags: snap.svg

how I can create a *group* element with id attribute in snap.svg ?

I tried to create it like this:

```
gr = draw.g(t1,t2);
gr.id="BoundingBox-"+BBoxElementCounter;
```

or

```
gr = draw.g(t1,t2);
gr.attr({"id": "BoundingBox-"+BBoxElementCounter});
```

But it is not working. Generated svg code is without id attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g.attr({id:"gid"})` should be the correct way - how are you validating that no id appears?

The code below was typed in the Chrome JavaScript console and verifies using `.outerSVG()` as well as inspection on the Elements tab.

```
Snap.version
"0.2.0"

var g = s.g()
undefined

g.attr({id:"gid"})
Element {id: "Shq33m2ni13", node: g#gid, paper: Element, type: "g", anims: Object…}

g.outerSVG()
"<g id="gid"/>"
```

Notice that version is `0.2.0` which I got from the [adobe-webplatform / Snap.svg](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg) GitHub repo.  If you have to use `0.1.0`, look at [apply ID to a snap.svg graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642312/apply-id-to-a-snap-svg-graphic) which uses the undocumented `node` property.

```
g.node.id = 'gid';
```

Comment: I used version 0.1.0 and I checked code through inspection on the Elements tab. Well I will check it in version 0.2.0